# How to access Local storage of Mobile browser in appium test using java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, appium-android

I want to access the local storage of mobile web browser chrome in the Appium test.

I am able to access Desktop browser local storage in the selenium java test using the below script.

```
    driver.get("https://google.com/");
    WebStorage webStorage = (WebStorage) driver;
    LocalStorage localStorage = webStorage.getLocalStorage();

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    String x = localStorage.getItem("deviceId");
    System.out.println(x);
```

When using the same script in appium getting below error

java.lang.ClassCastException: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.html5.WebStorage

Can somone guide me how to access Local storage key value in appium

Comment: Any solution arrived for the above ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the JavaScriptExecutor interface and just run a JavaScript command to retrieve data from local-storage? http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/web/execute/